# Bootable usb for linux (RHEL)

Tags: linux, windows-7

I want to create bootable usb for rhel linux from iso image. please suggest me methods, i can use window or linux itself for creating bootable usb/pen-drive.

Thanks

Comment: Boot from CD, and choose as installation target the USB-Drive. It is typically enumerated behind the hard drives, so if you have 2 harddrives, they're /dev/sda and sdb, and the usb would be sdc. But try to verify this, somehow (look for the size) to prevent overwriting the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), that should do what you want and is cross platform

Comment: What does it do that `dd if=linux.iso ...` doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I have always been successful by using the dd command:

```
dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

which assumes that linux.iso  is in the current directory and is a generic Linux .iso name used herein as an example only to substitute for an actual Linux .iso file name in order to illustrate the dd command usage, and where x is the letter of the USB device name which can be determined by using the Disk Utility application from System>Administration from the main menu bar (e.g. Ubuntu).